# How to change orientation(vertical and horizontal position of math formula) using react hooks(web app)?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change the orientation of the MATH formula between horizontal and vertical orientation using **react hooks**.

How can I make the formula change its orientation **every time I click the button**? - (from horizontal to vertical and vice versa)

I have tried this code but it doesn't work. (I am new to react)

This is App.js

```
 import './App.css';
 import Horizontal from './horizontal';
 import Vertical from './vertical';
 import { useState} from 'react'

 function App() {
   const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState(<Vertical/>)

   const clickOrientation = () => {
     if (orientation===<Horizontal/>){
        setOrientation(<Vertical/>)
       }

     else if (orientation === <Vertical />) {
        setOrientation(<Horizontal/>)
       }}
      console.log(orientation)

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {orientation}
     <button onClick={clickOrientation}>change orientation</button>      
    </div>
  )
  }

  export default App;
```

This is horizontal.jsx

```
  import React from 'react'

  function Horizontal() {
     return (
       <div>
        1 + 2
       </div>
 
    )
    }

  export default Horizontal
```

This is vertical.jsx

```
  import React from 'react'

  function Vertical() {
  return (
      <div>
        1 
      +
        2
    </div>
 
  )
  }

 export default Vertical
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case checking whether value is equals to a component will not work as expected. Therefore the best way to use your code is define a boolean or string with useState and use conditional rendering inside the return.

You can try one of the following methods.

### Method 1 (useState with string)

```
 import './App.css';
 import Horizontal from './horizontal';
 import Vertical from './vertical';
 import { useState} from 'react'

 function App() {
   const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState('vertical')

   const clickOrientation = () => {
     if (orientation==='vertical'){
       setOrientation('horizontal');
     }

     else if (orientation === 'horizontal') {
       setOrientation('vertical');
     }
   }

   return (
     <div className='App'>
       {
         orientation === 'vertical' ? (<Vertical />) : (<Horizontal />)
       }
       <button onClick={clickOrientation}>change orientation</button>      
     </div>
   )
 }

 export default App;
```

### Method 2 (useState with boolean)

```
 import './App.css';
 import Horizontal from './horizontal';
 import Vertical from './vertical';
 import { useState} from 'react'

 function App() {
   const [isVertical, setIsVertical] = useState(true)

   const clickOrientation = () => {
     if (isVertical){
       setIsVertical(false);
     } else {
       setIsVertical(true);
     }
   }

   return (
     <div className='App'>
       {
         isVertical ? (<Vertical />) : (<Horizontal />)
       }
       <button onClick={clickOrientation}>change orientation</button>      
     </div>
   )
 }

 export default App;
```

Note: Further consider about how to align items inside two components. In vertical component it's better to have `<br />` at the end of each line to break lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<br/>` tag to make it vertical

```
function Vertical() {
     return (
       <div>
        1 <br/> + <br/> 2
       </div>
 
    )
}
```

or separate them by `div` tag

```
function Vertical() {
    return (
        <>
            <div>1</div>
            <div>+</div>
            <div>2</div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `conditional-rendering` to render `Vertical` or `Horizontal`. You can read mỏe in: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html